# Prepending input value to textarea in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a script that prepends the contents of a text input to a textarea in real time

Here's what I currently have:

```
<textarea rows="4" id="tweet-text" name="tweet-text"></textarea>
<input id="prepend" name="prepend" type="text">
```

jQuery:

```
function appendTweet()
{
    var tweet = $("#tweet-text").val();
    $('#prepend').bind('keyup keypress', function() { 
        $('#tweet-text')[0].value = tweet + $(this)[0].value;
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    appendTweet();
    $('#prepend').keyup(appendTweet);
});
```

Currently my input is the previous string plus the new one, so if I typed hello I'd get

> h
>
> hhe
>
> hehel
>
> helhell
>
> hellhello

I can see why this is happening, but I can't find the solution.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I'm looking for the following outcome:

1. I type 'test ' into `#prepend`. `#tweet-text` now says 'test'.
2. I type 'test2' into `#tweet-text.` #tweet-text` now says 'test test2'.
3. I modify `#prepend` so that it now says 'test3 '. `#tweet-text` now says 'test3 test2'.

Comment: Please, be more specific in what you want to achieve: the user is allowed to type text into the text area? If so you want the text in the text area to be preserved while the text in the text box is prepended, right?

Comment: @Paolo No, I want it to be replaced. See my edit.

Comment: At point 2 you're typing in the text area. At point 3 you are preserving what have been typed into the text area "test2". Not replacing it.

Comment: Sorry, yes that's right. What goes in the textarea is preserved, what goes into the input is replaced.

Comment: I see a critical point here: you can keep the text area updated (in sync) so it always begins with `prepend` as the user writes text in `prepend`. But what if the user writes at the beginning of the text area, change the prepend string (from the text area) or just clear the whole text area?

Comment: try with this http://jsfiddle.net/Qtr7C/ to see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('#prepend').onkeydown(function() { 
     var tweet = $("#tweet-text").val();
     $('#prepend').val(tweet);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
function appendTweet()
{
    var tweet = $("#prepend").val();
    $('#tweet-text').val(function(index, old) { return tweet + old; });

}
```

This will prepend the textbox text in text area.

[**Here is Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Q3TX/)

Comment: Which part of this prepends what's in the input box?

Comment: val function of tweet-text

Comment: Thanks for the demo. Does it work for you? It's doing the same as what I described in my question.

Comment: you wanted to prepend textbox value in text area it is doing that

Comment: Yes, but I need only the current prepended text to be in the textarea. This is allowing them to accumulate.

Comment: It still isn't replacing the previous prepended text. I almost need two sections to the textarea: prepended text + body. And prepended text needs to be able to be replaced with something else.